# Deploying React app, Router is not correct

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on React app and trying to deploy on IIS.

It works fine but the Router is not showing correctly.

My expected path when I click the link 'Test' is 'http://localhost/test/TestRouter/' but it displays 'http://localhost/TestRouter/' instead.

Here is my code:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Test from './Test';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/TestRouter/">Test</Link>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </nav>

        <Route path="/TestRouter/" component={Test} />
      </div>
    </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Test.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Test</p>              
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

package.json:

```
"homepage": "/test/",
```

Then I deploy on IIS, under Default Web Site/test

My problem is when I click 'Test' link, the url now displays 'http://localhost/TestRouter/'.

My expectation is that the url should displays 'http://localhost/test/TestRouter/'.

Is there anyone here can help me to correct the Router?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `basename` to the Router:

```
 <Router basename='/test'>
```

Comment: Weird, the only thing I can think of is in addition to basename, remove all trailing slashes from your urls: `"homepage": "/test"`, `<Route path="/TestRouter/" component={Test} />`,etc.

Comment: Sorry mate, I added to Route, it should be added to Router instead. And it works now! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### path="test/TestRouter"

There is option to fill the path directly

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/test/TestRouter">Test</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <Route path="test/TestRouter" component={Test} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

And option like the comment here

```
<Router basename='/test'>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/TestRouter">Test</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <Route path="/TestRouter" component={Test} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

Did you sure you try this as it wrote?

Comment: so the url is correct now but my component Test doesn't show up